# PHP function declaration: function example(&$Test) { } Explain &?

Tags: php

In this example, what does the & accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ampersand means the function gets a reference to the variable. The php manual can explain it better than i can!

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 4):

It makes the parameter [pass by reference](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), instead of pass by value.

From php5 and above, it is not necessary to pass objects by reference anymore.

Answer (score 2):

`&` indicates that the variable is accessed by reference rather than by value. See the [PHP documentation on references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) for further information.